# LINQ extension methods not available for EnumerableRowCollection<TRow>

Tags: .net, linq

I have a following line of code:

```
var availableClients = (Controller.ListClientsForCurrentUser() as DataTable).AsEnumerable();
```

and I want to take advantage of LINQ's extension methods ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907979.aspx)) like **Any**. But those methods are not visible. What is going on? I can only see Where, Select and order by methods.

Comment: Do you have a `using System.Linq` declaration? Does the project have a reference to `System.Core`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you missing

```
using System.Linq;
```

by any chance? Once you've got an `EnumerableRowCollection<TRow>` it should be fine. (The main problem using a `DataTable` if if you forget to call `AsEnumerable`, but that isn't a problem here.)

Comment: I had all references but forgot about the fact that when using extension methods, using statement must be present. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Check that there are

```
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
```

and that you are referencing `System.Core` and `System.Data`